# Remove ui square when many touches

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am coding a game on a Touchscreen with many players at the same time. The issue is, when there are 2 or more touches, a little square is appearing on the screen. It seems to be a unity built-in feature as it is still present in an empty project.

Is there a way to prevent this annoying little square to appear ? I already disabled magic touch shortcuts in windows. And this doesn't appear on the desktop home screen.

I am able to listen to the touches. It seems to be only a visual thing.

Even when I disable multitouch with `Input.multiTouchEnabled = false;` It still appears.
I also tried to remove the 18 default Axes in the Input Manager.

My goal is to handle every touch separately, without listening to pinch, long press, or scroll interactions. Each player has only to tap somewhere on the screen.

Thanks for you time

[image: Illustration of the issue]

Comment: Are you using Old Input System or the New Input System?

Comment: I use the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself. I completely disabled Touch feedback in the windows parameters. I don't think it is the only way to do that but it works.

Configuration Panel > Pen and Touch

Unmark *"Show visual feedback when touching the screen"*